# Set color on active item in a BottomNavigationBarType.fixed

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I have a fixed BottomNavigationBar with 4 items as described below.

How can I set the color of the selected item?

I've tried with: fixedColor and selectedItemColor but it would't work.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            fixedColor: Colors.blue,
            //selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
            currentIndex: snapshot.data.index,
            onTap: _bottomNavBarBloc.pickItem,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.access_time,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(...),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(...),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(...),
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a different icon for Active and Normal Bottom Navigation Item.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem _getNavigationItem(IconData icon, String title) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        activeIcon: Icon(
          icon,
          color: Colors.teal,
        ),
        icon: Icon(icon, color: Colors.grey),
        title: Text(title),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks....this might be a solution, but because only icon have a different color it wouldn't feel that active as when you change the color of the icon also the title.

Comment: @AlexandraDamaschin Have you tried setting **selectedItemColor** and **unselectedItemColor** in **BottomNavigationBar**? I think you should try this. Also remove TextStyle from BottomNavigationBarItem when you apply above.

Comment: Indeed! Setting an active icon combined with unselectedItemColor/ selectedItemColor will make the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: @AlexandraDamaschin I'm glad that it works for you. Have a great day ahead.!!

Answer (score 1):

> There are two types available. fixed or shifting. If we add fixed type , the buttons inside bottom navigation does not show any effect when use click a particular button. It just keep fixed to the bottom navigation. If we add shifting , it will show some kind of cool animation when we click a particular button.

[Check this out here](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-6-bottom-navigation-38b202d9ca23)

A workaround perhaps would be something like this though:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("StackoverFlow"),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.access_time,
                color: currentIndex == 0? Colors.blue:Colors.black,
              ),
              title: Container(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.access_time,
                color: currentIndex == 1? Colors.blue:Colors.black,
              ),
              title: Container(),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the workaround I was thinking about as well, but I was hoping that there might be something from the library and I missed it. You are right because of what the docs says: "the buttons inside bottom navigation does not show any effect when use click a particular button" so there might not be any other way of implement it.

Comment: I'm glad! And yeah i doubt that there's something right away because the docs says that this was specifically made to not be altered. The active Icon thing works too as said by Dhaval. Please do accept an answer as well to close this! Good Day to u.